# Understanding Item-based collaborative filtering

Tags: recommender-system

I try to understand item based collaborative filtering by studying the recommenderlab [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf). On page 7 the calculation of expected ratings for items unrated by the user is very nicely illustrated but I cannot reproduce the results.

For item $i_3$ (row three of the matrix) the bold matrix elements are the $k = 3$ other most similar components and $\mathcal{S}(i_3) = \{i_2,i_5,i_8 \}$. The estimated rating for the third product is $$\hat{r}_{u3}  = 
\frac{0.8\cdot 0 +0.4 \cdot 4+0.5 \cdot 5}{0.8+0.4+0.5} = 2.41$$
but it is supposed to equal 4.6.

what am I doing wrong here?

[image: Screenshot of Page 7 of the recommenderlab documentation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My equation in the vignette of recomenderlab is unfortunately slightly incorrect since the weight is only the sum of the most similar components $S(i)$ for which we have user ratings (i.e., $r_{ai} \ne ?$).

The corrected equation is:

\begin{equation}
    \hat{r}_{ai} =  \frac{1}{\sum_{j \in S(i)\cap \{l\,;\,r_{al} \ne ?\}}{s_{ij}}} 
    \sum_{j \in S(i)\cap \{l\,;\,r_{al} \ne ?\}}{s_{ij} r_{aj}}
\end{equation}

This gives:
$$
\hat{r}_{a3}  = 
\frac{0.4 \cdot 4+0.5 \cdot 5}{0.4+0.5} = 4.6
$$

Unfortunately, the figure was also quite misleading, so I changed it as well (basically $u_a$ is now where $r_a$ was and vice versa).

Hope I got it right this time! Thanks for spotting the mistake. I will update the vignette for the next version of the package.

-Michael

Comment: I have a question regarding this calculation. I am trying to build an item based recommendation system. My question is what prediction do you assign if the intersection of the top k items and the user ratings are empty?

Comment: Then you just have no recommendation. In an actual implementation of a  recommender system, you probably will resort to recommending popular items instead.